# Comparing keys in a Json file with values in a List In python

Tags: python, json, loops, dictionary, web-scraping

I need to comapre the titles in this Json file with the titles in a list. My goal is to check what titles are equal to the values of this list and then print information about that title. For example if one of the titles is Bloons TD 6 I want to only print the corresponding description and viewableDate.

Here is what I have so far

```
response = requests.get("https://store-site-backend-static-ipv4.ak.epicgames.com/freeGamesPromotions?locale=en-US&country=US&allowCountries=US")

freeGameData = json.loads(response.text)
freeNowList = Epic_Scraper()

#freeNowList returns ['Bloons TD 6', 'Loop Hero']
#freeGameData returns the json listed below
```

The Json File looks like this

```
{
    "data": {
        "Catalog": {
            "searchStore": {
                "elements": [
                    {
                        "title": "Loop Hero",
                        "id": "db122f42b41f4dec927e0f280cf653bd",
                        "namespace": "ff50f85ed609454e80ac46d9496da34d",
                        "description": "The Lich has thrown the world into a timeless loop and plunged its inhabitants into never ending chaos. Wield an expanding deck of mystical cards to place enemies, buildings, and terrain along each unique expedition loop for the brave hero.",
                        "effectiveDate": "2021-03-04T18:00:00.000Z",
                        "offerType": "BASE_GAME",
                        "expiryDate": null,
                        "viewableDate": "2021-03-04T18:00:00.000Z",
                        "status": "ACTIVE",
                        "isCodeRedemptionOnly": false,
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Bloons TD 6",
                        "id": "b27e3b556f1048b9824c7196f32afceb",
                        "namespace": "6a8dfa6e441e4f2f9048a98776c6077d",
                        "description": "The Bloons are back and better than ever! Get ready for a massive 3D tower defense game designed to give you hours and hours of the best strategy gaming available.",
                        "effectiveDate": "2022-07-19T12:00:00.000Z",
                        "offerType": "BASE_GAME",
                        "expiryDate": null,
                        "viewableDate": "2022-04-30T00:00:00.000Z",
                        "status": "ACTIVE",
                        "isCodeRedemptionOnly": false,
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Destiny 2: Bungie 30th Anniversary Pack",
                        "id": "e7b9e222c7274dd28714aba2e06d2a01",
                        "namespace": "428115def4ca4deea9d69c99c5a5a99e",
                        "description": "The 30th Anniversary Pack includes a new Dungeon, Gjallarhorn Exotic Rocket Launcher, new weapons, armor, and much more.                    ",
                        "effectiveDate": "2022-08-23T13:00:00.000Z",
                        "offerType": "DLC",
                        "expiryDate": null,
                        "viewableDate": "2022-08-08T15:00:00.000Z",
                        "status": "ACTIVE",
                        "isCodeRedemptionOnly": false,
                        },
                    },

}
```

Comment: What problem are you having? Loop through the `elements` list. Test if the title is in the list, and if so, print what you want. It's a simple `if something in list:` test.

Comment: Your posted attempted code does not include any attempt to parse the json file and/or compare data. Please considering investing more in the question by following [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the innermost list of your json and only print the information if the title is in your list:

```
for e in freeGameData["data"]["Catalog"]["searchStore"]["elements"]:
    if e["title"] in freeNowList:
        print(e["description"])
        print(e["viewableDate"]+"\n")
```